# Automatic sticks in reverse briefly after shifting from reverse to drive

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, dodge

Got a mind boggle. Need some opinions.

A good friend of mine has an early 2000's Dodge Intrepid and when he starts the car and puts it in reverse the car starts backing up. When you stop to pull it down  to engage drive and apply throttle it stays in reverse for a few seconds then suddenly decided to allow the transmission to switch into drive and starts pulling forward.

Any ideas?

Is this a maintenance issue with fluid levels?

What are some troubleshooting techniques I can employ to discover the root cause of the problem?

Comment: Does that vehicle have shift indicator lights on the dash and, if so, do they also show reverse for a few seconds? I.e. do they match the intended gear, or do they match what the car is actually doing.

Comment: Check the trans fluid?

Comment: Has the trans fluid ever been changed and the trans filter changed?

Comment: Sounds like a sluggish servo or solenoid, possibly due to bad/dirty fluid.

Comment: I think the question is sound, please don't vote to close this.

Comment: Change the fluid and filter as already suggested by others. If that doesn't fix you will have to rebuild your transmission or drive it until it breaks completely and get rid of the car.

Comment: @DucatiKiller voted to close because OP has not responded to questions -  it's also a possible duplicate of these questions: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25197/engagement-delay-when-shifting-from-neutral-to-drive-or-reverse?rq=1 or http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26524/shifting-problem?rq=1

Comment: @MooseLucifer perhaps selecting 'other' as a reason and populating that the OP is unresponsive could help others to better understand the reason for the close.  I think all of us, me included, have struggled here.

Comment: @trigga can you respond to some of the questions regarding your issue.  I think you have an audience that is willing to assist.  If you can populate some additional information in your question related to the queries you could get a nice elegant answer that could be helpful.

Comment: He actually just scrapped the car because it suddenly wouldn't pull in any gear and the fluid had so much metal in it and it was just too far gone to put the amount of money and time it'd take to find and replace the tranny since its pretty much a disposable car to begin with. In my opinion the intrepid was a failed experiment anyway and without my opinion being spoken to him I think he came to that conclusion too. Thanks for all the help though guys.

Answer (score 0):

> "He actually just scrapped the car because it suddenly wouldn't pull
>   in any gear and the fluid had so much metal in it and it was just too
>   far gone to put the amount of money and time it'd take to find and
>   replace the tranny since its pretty much a disposable car to begin
>   with. In my opinion the intrepid was a failed experiment anyway and
>   without my opinion being spoken to him I think he came to that
>   conclusion too. Thanks for all the help though guys."

OP made effort to report closure to this situation.  This question is not useful in the database and probably should be closed.